# Apply a function to already existing Date column

Tags: python, pandas, function, date

I have below fictitious code (My code is sensitive):

```
df
record_id     date    sick funny    happy
XK2C0001-3  7/10/2018   2   1       1
XK2C0002-1  7/10/2018   2   4       1
XK2C0003-9  7/11/2018   2   4       1
ZT2C0004-7  7/11/2018   2   4       1
XK2C0005-4  7/11/2018   1   1       1
XK2C0001-3  7/10/2018   2   4       1
XK2C0002-1  7/10/2018   2   4       1
XK2C0003-9  7/11/2018   1   4       1
XK2C0004-7  7/11/2018   2   4       1
ZT2C0005-4  7/11/2018   2   4       1


male_gender=df.loc[(df['sick'] == 1) | (df['funny'] == 1) | (df['happy'] == 1)]
male_gender['date'].value_counts().head()
2018-10-02    22
2018-10-03    14
2018-10-05    10
2018-11-01    10
2018-10-22    10
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

and I have below working function to filter last 7 weekdays:

```
prev_days = [today - timedelta(days=i) for i in range(10)]  
prev_days = [d for d in prev_days if d.weekday() < 5]       
for d in prev_days[:7]:                                     
    print(d)
```

My question is: How to apply the function above to the dataframe column "date"? I just want the idea, the data  above are fictitious, you may give another example.

**Edit: I want to know how many male_gender do I have in the last 7 weekdays relative to today only.**

Comment: What do you want your function to do, just `print`? That's pretty extreme / inefficient. You want to `print` an *entire dataframe for each row of your input*?

Comment: @jpp, I want to print total counts of male_gender=df.loc[(df['sick'] == 1) | (df['funny'] == 1) | (df['happy'] == 1)] in the last 7 week days. Do you understand?

Comment: Sadly, no, I don't. You want to print an entire series *for each row*?

Comment: I want to know how many male_gender do I have in the last 7 weekdays

Comment: `last 7 weekdays` relative to what? Today? An arbitrary day?

Comment: Yes, relative to today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your `df['date']` to a `datetime` series, filter your dataframe, and *then* use [`pd.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

m1 = (df['sick'] == 1) | (df['funny'] == 1) | (df['happy'] == 1)  # custom conditions
m2 = df['date'] >= pd.Timestamp('today') - pd.DateOffset(days=7)  # last 7 days
m3 = ~df['date'].dt.weekday.isin([5, 6])                          # not Sat or Sun

res = df.loc[m1 & m2 & m3, 'date'].value_counts()
```

Comment: I followed your solution, applied to my real dataset and I got below error: 
----> 7 res = df.loc[m1 & m2 & m3, 'date'].values_counts()
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'values_counts'

Comment: @MGB.py, That was a typo, you need `value_counts` instead of `values_counts`.

Comment: It works but I need to tune it up a little. 
Can you explain in details (comments) your code? I am not understanding it.
Also, I would like to see dates from here res = df.loc[m1 & m2 & m3, 'date'].value_counts() and also add one more column to see the place of occurence. How to add one more column along with date?

Comment: That's a bit more complicated, I suggest asking [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).